# grub-mkrescue generates corrupted iso

Tags: operating-system

I have recently started making an operating system. After a lot of coding, I made a basic kernel written in Assembly and C that just prints a single character. The kernel.bin file works fine (i am sure because i tested it with Qemu.). I decided to use Grub because i do not have time to write my own bootloader.

I have generated an .iso image using the `grub-mkrescue` command but when I try to boot it in Virtualbox, I get the error in the image below. It would be a pleasure if you could help me. I run Linux Mint 18 64bit.

[image]

[grub.cfg file (Google Drive)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4_SPo2PIAk2b1hNVlgxT0podFU)